# How can I set the value of collapsed inside a collapsible panel depending on a condition?-EXTJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a collapsible panel:

```
$cls.superclass.constructor.call(this, Ext.apply({
        panel = new Ext.Panel({
            title: "Panel",
            collapsed: true,
            items: [
                this.section({
                    items: [
                        this.filter = new Ext.form.DisplayField({})
                    ]
                })
            ],

            collapsible: true,
        })
    });

    Ext.extend($cls, frame.mono.dialog.ObjectPanel, {

            afterRender: function(rule) {
                $cls.superclass.afterRender.apply(this, arguments);
                //depending on some condition I'm trying to change the value of collapsed to false
                //if (//some condition) {
                this.panel.collapsed = false;
                this.panel.doLayout(); // this is not working
            }

        }
    });
```

How can I set the value of collapsed inside a collapsible panel depending on a condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [toggleCollapse](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.panel.Panel.html#method-toggleCollapse) method to achieve what you are trying to do. Do it inside the beforerender event.

Please refer following fiddle -

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2kvv